# Probability Mass Function and expected value

Tags: probability

Voice calls cost 0.20 cent each and data calls cost 0.30 cent each. C is the cost of one telephone
call. The probability that a call is a voice call is P[V] = 0.6. The probability of a data call is
P[D] = 0.4.
a) Find $P_C(c)$, the PMF of C.
b) Find E[F], the expected value of F.

in first question i didn't understand the question, is it asking probability of cost equals another unknown? Isn't $P_C(c) = P[C=c]$ ?

Comment: Yes. It can be written by using a table. Or you can write $f_C(c)=\begin{cases} \ldots \\ \ldots  \end{cases}$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$P_C(c=0.2)=0.6$ and $P_C(c=0.3)=0.4$. This is the PMF of C.

$E[C]=0.2\times 0.6+0.3\times 0.4=0.24$